# Javascript fetch append data to HTML overwritten

Tags: javascript, html, fetch

Fairly new to Javascript. I've got a HTML form with **onsubmit** attribute equal to my JavaScript function getResponse(). In the getResponse() function I do a fetch (POST) to retrieve data from my API. I want to append the data to the page for the user to see, however, it seems to get wiped from the screen within milliseconds of it appearing on the screen.

My function getResponse():

```
fetch('/', {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
})
        .then(json)
        .then(function (data) {
            $(".formResponse").append(`<p>Response: ${data.user}`)
        })
        .then(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
```

It's a similar situation to if I console log the data it will disappear unless I 'preserve' the log in dev tools. Any suggestions, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: did you prevent the `onsubmit` event from performing its default action?

Comment: `.then(json)` should be `.then(response => response.json())`

Answer (score 3):

You need to prevent the default behavior of the form submitting. you can do this by calling `preventDefault()` on the event passed from `onsubmit`:

```js
 function getResponse(event) {
     // Prevent the default behavior of the form submitting.
     event.preventDefault()

     fetch('/', {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
})
        .then(json)
        .then(function (data) {
            $(".formResponse").append(`<p>Response: ${data.user}`)
        })
        .then(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
 }
```

The `<form>` `onsubmit` is passed an `event` argument, so you would then do the following on your form:

```html
<form onsubmit="getResponse(event);"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite see from this code why the data would disappear.

You should use a GET method to retrieve data. POST is used to create a record or save something.

The CRUD methods associated with http requests are the following.

GET / RETRIEVE - to retrieve data from a remote server. Like 'Open'.
POST / CREATE - to save or create data to a database. Like 'Save As'.
PUT / UPDATE - to update or save extra data to an already existing record. Like 'Save'.
DELETE / DESTROY - to delete a record.

If that doesn't work you might have to add some more of your code so we can see what's going on.